# Laravel route url?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have just completed the Basic Task List laravel tutorial. But when i click on "Add task" button the url i get is http://localhost/task instead of http://localhost/laravel5.1/public/task which it should be. I have searched a bit but i could find an answear you to make the url pointing correctly. By the way i had forgoten to add the **Application URL** in the config/app.php. I added it, and creared cache with the `php artisan cache:clear` command but still nothing. My laravel version is 5.1 .

Comment: Laravel is designed for the 'web root' to be the `public` folder - everything else shouldn't be web accessible. Setting the 'application url' in `config/app.php` is only used when you are running an artisan command, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I set the public folder as root in my appache. Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason :** You should configure your application first and generate url properly

**How :** Inside `config/app.php`set the 'url' => 'http://youraddresshost'

**Note :**

Changing the public folder as root in your apache is not the better solution, it won't work if you are moving the project to live server and you have multiple projects in it.

So, You should Generate your url in Laravel way i.e., via helper so that you can pointed to the correct destination.

Read more about Generating URL with laravel [here](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html#generating-urls)

Even you can do this to generate the url as suggested [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-url)

```
echo url('user/profile');

echo url('user/profile', [1]);
```

Also, if you do some jquery function to redirect the url on button click, you should generate url accordingly.

Hope, this helps you